# Heroku Python only handling first exception

Tags: python, heroku, flask, error-handling, twilio

### The aim

To send custom text messages based on data read in from a csv file. Text messages should only be sent if the recipient is new or if previous messages to the recipient successfully delivered. If the phone number from the csv file is invalid for any reason, the program should just skip to the next number.

#### The problem

When deployed to Heroku, only the first exception is correctly handled. No messages are sent after the second invalid phone number is processed. However, it appears to work correctly if I run the program locally from the terminal.

#### The code

```
def send_sms(num, msg):
    # sends message using Twilio's REST API
    message = client.messages.create(
        to=num, 
        from_=number,
        body=msg,
        status_callback=url)

def prep_msg(file):
    # iterate through csv file containing phone numbers
    for row in file:
        msg = 'test message'
        num = row[7]
        # look for recipient in database of previously sent messages
        record = Status.query.filter_by(to=num).first()
        if record == None or record.status == 'delivered':
            try:
                send_sms(num, msg)
            except Exception:
                continue
    return render_template('success.html')
```

Comment: Are there any clues in the logs from Heroku? Are there error messages there at all? Which version of Python are you running locally and on Heroku?

Comment: Nothing! All I see are the POST requests to the callback url, as expected, however they stop after the second invalid phone number is processed when I run the code locally. I'm running 3.6.1 both locally and on Heroku.

Comment: Is it different data between your local test data and the data on your server?

Comment: Nope, I'm reading in the same csv file...

Comment: Can you add some logging in around the call to `send_sms` and where you catch the exception to make sure that is happening successfully. If you `except Exception as ex:  print(ex)` what do you get?

Comment: I've added print statements when: a number gets assigned to num, when the if statement is entered, when send_sms() is called, after the exception is caught, and when the for loop ends. valid number 1!
in the if statement!
sent!
invalid number!
in the if statement!
HTTP 400 error: Unable to create record: The 'To' number 61999 is not a valid phone number.
valid number 2!
in the if statement!
sent!
invalid number!
in the if statement!
HTTP 400 error: Unable to create record: The 'To' number 61999 is not a valid phone number.
valid number 3!
valid number 4!
finished for loop!

Comment: Was that running on Heroku? That looks like it worked?

Comment: Yeah, it was. Sorry, it's hard to format in the comments but it only called send_sms() (and therefore printed 'sent!') twice when it should have called it four times. I'm starting to think it's got something to do with the way Heroku dynos/processes work? I don't know anything about them but am reading the docs now...

Comment: If you need to add things that have formatting you can edit your question. That is interesting that the loop ran for each of the items, it just didn't try to send the SMS for the last two. Are you sure they are in the state of `record == None or record.status == 'delivered'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was to send the messages asynchronously as a background task using one of Heroku's worker dynos.
I used the following resources to research this:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-rq

http://python-rq.org/docs/